# Cannot create groups in GCP or Google Groups - as owner

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-groups

Just wanting to start to setup a GCP environment for my own domain, play around some. Running into a setup issue where I cannot create Groups, whether from GCP (Menu > "IAM & Admin" > Groups) or just Google Groups.

Google Groups tells me I haven't got the correct permissions. Google Cloud Platform tells me I'm missing required permission `cloudidentity.groups.create`.

[image: GCP Error]

[image: Google Groups error]

I managed to create a bunch of groups in Google Admin, but they're not the right ones (apparently).

Now, I'm owner of my domain, it has Google for Work (Basic) and I've enable Cloud Identity (apparently do not need it as it's just for me, but was running low on ideas).

**Any idea how to fix this?**

Google's help pages send me in circles. Google GCP & Admin docs likewise keep telling me to just "click Create".

Comment: What roles have you assigned to the IAM identity that you are using in the Google Cloud Console? Since you are using Cloud Identity, you will need to go to Cloud Identity to add permissions to your account (cloudidentity.groups.create) and not the Google Cloud Console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, this is very silly, but: you must have "Groups for Business" turned on in the [Admin Console](https://admin.google.com) as an App for everything to start working.

With the App "Groups for Business" turned off, you can still create Groups (lol, whut?), assign them to Users, but somehow, they don't work.

Turning on Groups for Business and going back into the "Getting started" in [Google Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) magically got it to work.

(P.s. - I don't recall turning the App off, it's been years since I looked at that)

[image: Turn on this App]

Comment: Worked for me in 2023.